# How to test my class with data coming outside?

Tags: unit-testing

Seems I have pretty obvious question related to code testing. I have a class, which takes `json` objects from several sources, modifies and merges them. This class is covered with unit tests. Inside of this class I have stub objects with defined structure, which I return for testing. But one of the resources changed it's structure and now my code isn't working correctly. However all tests are passing.

So, I wonder, what should I do. Should I add tests, which will take real data from sources and test a class with this data? Is it called integration test?

Comment: This is a conceptual question -- and although a good one, doesn't appear to be a good fit for this community.

Comment: if the stability of you class behaviour depends on the real data , you should keep in mind , that your tests are not written correctly. Secondly, yes, you should check your class with data, that comes in better, but istead of getting real data,(database or cache) more ofter people write bundles

Comment: @Altenrion what is bunlde?

Comment: in different comunities and for different languages there are different uncommon solutions. In Java, I saw , people were writing some kind of link funcs, if the class is working with database. When unit test is calling it, this func triggers and gets the data not from real DB, but from prepeared storage. so by that , they were automating whole process of development, without need of writing class decorator for unit test of whole itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have data that you can get, and store, that would be easier than  to review your test data to make sure that you have appropriate coverage.

I'm afraid that fabricating data will not expose bugs, arising from changes in the database.

That's not the point of unit testing, if your tests depend on LIVE data, then it's an **integration test**.

For your unit tests, get a snapshot of data that covers ***ALL situations*** (or as many as possible that already exist) from the database and use that for your unit tests, and fabricate any edge cases with the help of a BA (Business Analyst).

If your requirements don't change, your tests won't get out of date. If your requirements do change, you'd need to update the tests anyway.